# Proving $\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, integers, normal-subgroups

This question is asking me to show that the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are a normal subgroup of the following group: $$\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{a + bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

I have come up with $3$ separate ways to do this (to varying degrees of success) and would like feedback on if they would be the correct ways to approach this problem as well as any guidance on areas I've come up short in the execution.

1. The first method that came to mind would be using Lagrange's Theorem and specifically the fact that any normal subgroup has index $2$. So Lagrange's Theorem states that (in this case) $\lvert \mathbb{Z}[i] \rvert = [\mathbb{Z}[i]:\mathbb{Z}] \lvert \mathbb{Z} \rvert$ so for the fact to hold we need $\lvert \mathbb{Z}[i] \rvert = 2 \cdot \lvert \mathbb{Z} \rvert$. We can see this is the case, informally, by noting that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has $2$ "copies" of $\mathbb{Z}$ in it; one for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and one for $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

   - Now, for this I would like to try and formalize this argument using notation if possible. If the 'informal' method of noting that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has $2$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ in it which can run all of $\mathbb{Z}$ is sufficient however that would be good to know.
2. The second method is noting that for any normal subgroup the left cosets equal the right cosets for all possible cosets. For that, let $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be any element then we have:

   - Left cosets have the form: $z+k = (a+bi) + k = (a+k) +bi, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$
   - Right cosets have the form:$k+z = k + (a+bi) = (k+a) + bi, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$
   - Since addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative we can see that $a + k = k + a$ and hence $(a + k) + bi = z+k = k+z = (k+a)+bi, \forall k,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $$z\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}z,\ \forall z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$$
3. The third method I could think of trying was to utilize the fact that normal subgroups are kernels of homomorphisms and so I tried coming up with a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $ker(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}$. To that end, let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $$\phi(a +bi) = Re(a+bi) = a$$ We can see this is a homomorphism by computing: $$\phi((a+bi)+(c+di)) = \phi((a+c)+(b+d)i) = Re((a+c)+(b+d)i) = a+c = \phi(a+bi)+\phi(c+di)$$ Now we want to show that $\mathbb{Z} =ker(\phi)$. In this case we see that $ker(\phi) = \{ (a+bi) \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \mid \phi(a+bi) = 0 \}$ but this only happens when $a = 0$. So clearly my homomorphism is not the correct one, any guidance on how to amend it would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Summary**

For part $1.$ I would just like to know how to formalize this argument, or if my informal type argument would be sufficient for a proof.

For part $2$. I think this part is okay, but obviously open for critique in case I missed something.

For part $3$. I would like to know how to amend or change my homomorphism to ensure that the kernel is all of the integers.

Comment: Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: For part 1: what happens if you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a finite group, eg $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, with a similar addition law? Part 2 is basically okay but mixes uncomfortably additive and multiplicative notation (not serious) and necessary/sufficient conditions for normal subgroups (*very* bad). You should say that the right and left cosets associated to $\mathbb{Z}$ and any $z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ match, and *therefore* the subgroup is normal (see also lulu’s comment). For part 3: you want a homomorphism of $(a,b)$ whose kernel is the integers, so exactly when $b=0$. Any ideas?

Comment: It is false that "any normal subgroup has index 2". What is true is that every subgroup of index 2 is normal (the implication goes the other way).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes that's right, my apologies for being so sloppy with my statements of facts. It is not an if and only if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lulu is right in their comment - in an abelian group, every subgroup is normal. In fact you prove this precisely in your Part 2 - notice how you only use the fact that addition is commutative.

Part 1 is probably doomed to fail - $ \mathbb{Z} $ does not have index 2, but infinite index.

Part 3 seems almost fine - try mapping to the imaginary part instead of the real part!